# Visual Studio has stopped show hints when pointer goes over class names, functions, properties etc

Tags: visual-studio

Now there are just small icon that says nothing useful. I've tried to reinstall vs but without any success. It happened with Unity solution but it doesn't seem issue has something to do with Unity, since I've also checked it by creating new solution as a "console application" with the same result.
[image]

I've tried to update/reinstall Visual Studio.

Visual Studio community 8.10.25(build2). Mac OS Ventura 13.0.1

I've managed to solve it by downloading installer of vs directly from the site, without Unity Hub. It installs non "community" version of vs instead of what hub does.

Comment: I only have the windows version of MSVS, but let's see if we can T&E this. What languages do you use? All C-related languages or strictly C# (since you did mention Unity). Show us a prntscr of the TextEditor -> C# -> Advanced and TextEditor -> C# -> Intellisense (or their equivalent on macOS VS).

Comment: @TheNomad There is no path you mentioned, so I just added prntscr of Intellisense settings that is there. I use C# and it seems there is nothing else but C# anf F#

Comment: Hm, unfortunately it's quite different from the Win MSVS. I was hoping I could help. Have you checked the options inside *Behavior* and *Code Snippets* that could possibly be responsible for the helper hints?

Comment: I see nothing there that may have something to do with the issue...

Comment: Previously I've used unity-hub to install/update vstudio and that did not help, but regular installation (just downloading installer from vs-site directly) solved the issue.

Comment: Ubity Hub installs "community" version, but what I've installed is just vstudio without any prefixes. So, maybe that's the key-point.